Why Can't Countability be Expressed in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$?
I've recently be learning about infinitary logics, including Scott Sentences. In the logic $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (which allows for countably infinite conjunctions and disjunctions, but only finitely nested quantifiers), any countable model $M$ has a sentence $\psi_M$ with the property that for countable models $N$, $N \vDash \psi_M \iff N \simeq M$.
Which raises the question, why do we need to only consider countable models?
In certain theories, like Peano Arithmetic, we can write a sentence $\phi_c := \forall x: (x = 0 \vee x = S(0) \vee x = S(S(0)) \vee \cdots)$ which only has countable models.
But in general, in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ with equality only, is there a sentence $\psi$ that has only countably infinite models? That is, $M \vDash \psi \implies ||M|| = \aleph_0$? If not, why not?

One (slightly heuristic) way to convince yourself that this is not true is by noting that truth of $L_{\infty,\omega}$-sentences is absolute between forcing extensions. Two things that follow from it are: (i) satisfying the same $L_{\infty,\omega}$-sentences is the same as being isomorphic in a forcing extension, and (ii) the properties described by $L_{\infty,\omega}$-sentences are arguably much more intrinsic compared to cardinality (although some implications may be true, as in the case of the Scott sentence of $\mathbf N$).

(Mind, in the specific case of $L$ being just equality, this is actually precise and not heuristic at all, as explained by Noah.)

This is a very nice question! The answer is indeed no: if $\varphi$ is a sentence true in every countable structure, then $\varphi$ is true in at least some uncountable structures as well.
For $\alpha$ an ordinal, let $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ be a pure set with cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$. I claim that $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{S}_\beta$ satisfy the same $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentences for every pair of ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ (in particular look at $\alpha=0,\beta=1$). My favorite proof of this is via Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games. These are usually introduced for first-order logic specifically, but variants on the original game have applications to other logics as well (as in this case). Briefly, the set $\mathbb{F}_{\alpha,\beta}$ of finite partial bijections between $\mathcal{S}_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{S}_\beta$ is a "back-and-forth system of length $\omega^*$" (see the presentation in Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas for this terminology), and by induction this gives the desired result.
In fact it gives much more than that - it shows that $\mathcal{S}_\alpha\equiv_{\infty,\omega}\mathcal{S}_\beta$ - and indeed $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$'s "game characterization" is much more complicated than either $\mathcal{L}_{\omega,\omega}$s or $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$s, see Vaananen/Wang or this old MO question of mine.
Similarly, two dense linear orders without endpoints of any cardinality whatsoever are $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$-equivalent, and so e.g. $(\mathbb{Q};<)$ and $(\mathbb{R};<)$ satisfy the same $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentences.
